# Seeing errors in QueueTrigger - Azure WebJobs SDK 3.0

Tags: autofac, azure-webjobssdk, .net-4.7.1

I am in the process of upgrading an Azure Web Job with a Queue Trigger from 2.2 to 3.0.4.  I added the storage extension Nuget package, changed the configuration code and got the application to run.

It is able to pull from the queue, but I am not able to see any errors nor hit any breakpoints locally in my queue trigger function.  I know that the messages are being picked up because it is the only application pointed to my local storage emulator (with a unique queue name) and all messages go straight to poison queue a few seconds after being added.  I never see an error in the console though.

I am using Autofac, as the 2.2 implementation worked fine with it - I included the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package.

Here is my main in program.cs - breakpoints hit fine inside here, but not in the QueueProcessor:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.Write("Initializing DI container...");

        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        RegisterTypes(containerBuilder);
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<BulkUpdateRequestProcessor>();
        containerBuilder.Build();

        Console.Write("done.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Initializing host configuration...");
        var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder();
        hostBuilder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
            .AddAzureStorage(options =>
             {
                 options.BatchSize = 1;
                 options.MaxDequeueCount = 1;
                 options.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5f);
             });

            b.AddTimers();

            b.AddExecutionContextBinding();
            b.AddDashboardLogging();


        })
        .ConfigureServices((x) => x.AddAutofac())
        .UseConsoleLifetime();

        Console.Write("done.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        var host = hostBuilder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }

    }
```

Queue Processor:

```
public class BulkUpdateRequestProcessor
{
    private readonly IRevisionService _revisionService;

    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IClock _clock;

    public BulkUpdateRequestProcessor(IRevisionService revisionService, ILogger logger, IClock clock)
    {
        _revisionService = revisionService;
        _logger = logger;
        _clock = clock ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clock));
    }

    public async Task ProcessNewJobRequest([QueueTrigger(BulkUpdateConstant.BULK_UPDATE_JOB_QUEUE)] Guid jobId, TextWriter log)
    {
        _logger.Info(string.Format("New item appeared in a queue: '{0}'", jobId));

        try
        {
            await ProcessJobRequest(jobId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Error, ex);
            await TryNotifyJobFailed(jobId, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        _logger.Info(string.Format("Request '{0}' processed", jobId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the class containing Web Job bindings require a zero parameter constructor.  I found this out by accident though.  It would be nice if a build error would have occurred.  -1 Microsoft